# XML regex: Is there any special functions for '-' symbol?

Tags: xml, regex

I had been searching a few sources online but none able to tell what this regex term matches for:

```
regex="^0-"
```

I knew `^` means starting of the string and `0` is just 0, but what is the meaning of `-` carrying behind? If it would mean just a literal char `-`, shouldn't it be written as `^0\-` with a slash `\` followed by a dash?

Besides, will this `regex="Stain"` matches both string:
`Stain` and `Sub-Stain`?

Thanks
Chun Meng

Comment: the system filtered my "\" slash symbol. The complete sentence would be: "If it would mean just a char '-', shouldn't it be written as "^0\-" with the slash follow by the dash.

Comment: What have you actually tried? https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0):

> regex="^0-"
>   I knew ^ means starting of the string and 0 is just 0, but what is the meaning of '-' carrying behind? If it would mean just a char '-', shouldn't it be written as "^0-" with a slash "\" followed by a dash?

`-` not a regex special special character. So you don't need to escape `-` symbol. But you must escape `-` when it is used within character class. `-` inside character class acts like a range operator. ex, `[0-9]`

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) question.

> Besides, will this regex="Stain" matches both string: "Stain" & "Sub-Stain"?

Yes the regex `Stain` matches the string `Stain` and also the substring `Stain` in `Sub-Stain`